# How get paymants list with PayPal .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, paypal

I trying get list of payment transactions with next code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

        var payments = Payment.List(apiContext);
    }
```

But I receive empty list. How I can get payment history info with PayPal .NET SDK?

Comment: [Possibly relevant?](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/312)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using [merchant-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(config);

        var req = new TransactionSearchReq
        {
            TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType("2019-06-20T11:00:00Z")
        };

        var data = service.TransactionSearch(req);

    }
```